# Uploading local project into an existing branch using git

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I am trying to upload a project I have depeloped in local (100% offline) into a branch of an existing repository but I don't know what I need to do to upload it.

I have used git in other situations and I understand the branches but this project is a big part of code and I don't feel with enough experience with git to upload it.

The main problem is that my code is not linked with the "master" of the repository I need to upload the code, so I don't think I can create a branch and link it with my code.

If something is unclear tell me in the comments and I will try to explain me better.

Comment: Not clear where are you facing problem. Can you tell what you tried and where you feel stuck?

Comment: sure Gaurav, I don't know what git commands I need to use to achieve my objective (upload my project(not in git) into an existing branch of another project) I don't know if I need to git clone and then change the branch and add there my code or if there's a good way to do this.